# insert stored procedure

Tags: java, jdbc, callable-statement

here is my procedure..and code when i click ok button it shows...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Masters.DesignationMaster.actionPerformed(DesignationMaster.java:423)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

//my procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `desig_procedure`(

    IN designation_id       int(10), 

    IN designation_name     varchar(20)

)
BEGIN
    insert into designation_master
(
    designation_id,
    designation_name
)
VALUES
(
    designation_id,
    designation_name
);

END
```

// Java Code

```
if(!"".equals(editDesignationIDTextField.getText()) && !"".equals(editDesignationNameTextField.getText()))
        {
            con= new InitializeDatabase();
            //con.getConnection();
                try
                {
                    CallableStatement stmt=(CallableStatement) con.connection.prepareCall("{call desig_procedure(?,?)}");
                    stmt.setString("" + editDesignationIDTextField.getText(),"" + editDesignationNameTextField.getText());
                    stmt.execute();

                }
                catch (SQLException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try {
                        if(con.connection != null && !con.connection.isClosed())
                        {
                            con.connection.close();
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException ex) 
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
      }
```

what is the problem where am i getting this wrong..i have connection made..and working fine hence tested from a file InitialiseDatabse.java..please help..

Comment: what is line no 423? : DesignationMaster.java:423

Comment: What is your question? Please be clear..!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
stmt.setString("" + editDesignationIDTextField.getText(),
    "" + editDesignationNameTextField.getText());
```

You're not setting the parameters in the right way:

```
stmt.setString(1, "" + editDesignationIDTextField.getText());
stmt.setString(2, "" + editDesignationNameTextField.getText());
```

Note, your `String` conversion works but is not the best way to do it. Since the `getText` method already returns a `String`, you don't need the `"" +` part:

```
stmt.setString(1, editDesignationIDTextField.getText());
stmt.setString(2, editDesignationNameTextField.getText());
```

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/9501207/1065197 (the database code is for Oracle but the Java code is similar for MySQL RDBMS).